# apt-get update fails with https sources broken during Docker engine installation on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker

I'm following the official documentation of [docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.

After the below step,

```
 echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

When I try to `sudo apt-get update`, I get the error:

```
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https received a segmentation fault.
```

If I remove the `docker.list` file and run `sudo apt-get update', then it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an alternate official method from Canonical: `apt install docker.io`. That's it. Anyway your error doesn't appear at first glance to be directly related to the method.

Comment: You have the choice between installing the version provided by the distribution or by upstream. upstream is more recent but is less integrated. distribution is older but better integrated (and for this case "de-vendored" where possible).

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you @A.B